# How to Auto Open or refresh or reload my Form when the date i set in reminders the same with the date in my computer?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, vba, visual-studio

I made a program Reminder System that Auto send email when the date i set in my apps  much the date in my computer. the problem is i need to restart my apps so that the reminder will show or the form will be loaded. if not it will not alert. so i need your help guys if the date change in my computer my apps will auto reload or refresh so that if have reminders it will be send to email. btw my program will be installed in a server that will always be open so i just need to auto reload my form every time the date change. below is my code in setting the reminders.

```
  Imports System.IO
  Public Class Reminder
Dim m As MsgBoxResult
Dim t As String
Private Sub Reminder_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
    Dim m1 As MsgBoxResult
    t = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Month.ToString & MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Day.ToString
    If Date.Today = MonthCalendar1.TodayDate And File.Exists(t & ".txt") = True Then
 m1 = MsgBox("You set a reminders for today. Would you like to send to EMAIL ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If m1 = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            MonthCalendar1.Enabled = False
            MonthCalendar1.Hide()
            Notetxt.Enabled = True
            Notetxt.Show()
            SaveBtn.Enabled = True
            SaveBtn.Show()
            Backbtn.Enabled = True
            Backbtn.Show()
            Addbtn.Enabled = True
            Addbtn.Show()
            delbtn.Enabled = True
            delbtn.Show()
            Notetxt.Text = File.ReadAllText(t & ".txt")
            sendEmail.Show()
            sendEmail.emailtxt.Text = Notetxt.Text
            sendEmail.Hide()
            MsgBox("SEND EMAIL SUCCESSFUL", vbOKOnly)
            lblMessage.Hide()

        End If
    End If



End Sub

Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
    t = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Month.ToString & MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Day.ToString
    Try
        If File.Exists(t & ".txt") = True Then
            MonthCalendar1.Enabled = False
            MonthCalendar1.Hide()
            Notetxt.Enabled = True
            Notetxt.Show()
            SaveBtn.Enabled = True
            SaveBtn.Show()
            Backbtn.Enabled = True
            Backbtn.Show()
            Notetxt.Text = File.ReadAllText(t & ".txt")
            Addbtn.Enabled = True
            Addbtn.Show()
            delbtn.Enabled = True
            delbtn.Show()
            lblMessage.Hide()

        Else
            m = MsgBox("Would you like to enter a reminders for this date?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
            If m = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                MonthCalendar1.Enabled = False
                MonthCalendar1.Hide()
                Notetxt.Enabled = True
                Notetxt.Show()
                Notetxt.Text = ""
                SaveBtn.Enabled = True
                SaveBtn.Show()
                Backbtn.Enabled = True
                Backbtn.Show()
                Addbtn.Enabled = True
                Addbtn.Show()
                delbtn.Enabled = True
                delbtn.Show()
                lblMessage.Hide()

            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Backbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Backbtn.Click
    Notetxt.Enabled = False
    Notetxt.Hide()
    MonthCalendar1.Enabled = True
    MonthCalendar1.Show()
    SaveBtn.Hide()
    Addbtn.Hide()
    delbtn.Hide()
    Backbtn.Hide()
    lblMessage.Show()


End Sub

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click

    t = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Month.ToString & MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Day.ToString

    Try
        If Notetxt.Text = "" Then
            If File.Exists(t & ".txt") = True Then
                File.Delete(t & ".txt")

            End If
        End If

        If Notetxt.Text.Length > 0 Then
            File.WriteAllText(t & ".txt", Notetxt.Text)
            MsgBox("SAVE SUCCESS", vbOKOnly)

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Addbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Addbtn.Click
    Notetxt.Text = "Hi QC Engineer, Golden Sample meet Due date already please change." & Environment.NewLine & "MODEL: " & Environment.NewLine & "START DATE: " & Environment.NewLine & "DUE DATE: " & Environment.NewLine & "APPROVED BY: EAKKACHAI"
End Sub

Private Sub delbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delbtn.Click
    Notetxt.Clear()
    File.Delete(t & ".txt")


End Sub


 End Class
```

and below is my code for sending email.

```
 Public Class sendEmail
Private Sub sendEmail_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Content As String
    Content = emailtxt.Text
    emailtxt.Text = Reminder.Notetxt.Text
    Dim Outlook As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
    Dim MailItem As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
    MailItem = Outlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    With MailItem
        .HTMLBody = emailtxt.Text
        .Subject = "GOLDEN SAMPLE DUE DATE EXPIRED"
        'use the below to change from the default email account
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "your@email.com"
        'you can add multiple recipients using .Add()
        .Recipients.Add("your@email.com")
        'examples of other optional arguments that can be included
        ' .Attachments.Add([file])
        .Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh
        .Send() 'opens the email for checking prior to sending or use .Send()
    End With
End Sub
```

End Class